# getName() returns null

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I came across this block of code in an extension that loops through child products and attempts to return their current stock qty and the child products name:

```
<?php foreach ($this->getChildProducts() as $childProduct) : ?>
        <?php $childProductStockQty = $this-> getProductStockQty($childProduct);?>
        <?php if ($childProductStockQty > 0) : ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $childProduct->getName() ?></td>
                <td class="a-center"><?php echo $childProductStockQty ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endif ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

In `CE 1.9.0.1` this worked perfectly, returning both product names and stock quantities as expected. In `CE 1.9.1`, it will return the correct stock quantities, but the name returns null.

My question isn't so much 'what's wrong with this extension?', I've sent a question to the developer as well. I'm wondering if any of you are aware if there are changes in `CE 1.9.1` in how to retrieve a child product name.

Reading the code down the `Mage/CatalogInventory/Block/Stockqty` rabbit hole hasn't shed any light that I can detect.

Any and all advice is appreciated.

Comment: Did you log the `$childProduct' and check the value of `[name]?

Comment: Are the two systems identical? My guess would be that in the system that does not return tr name, maybe the attribute has "no" in "display on category listings"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats interesting that name is returning null. Hunting through the code it ends up in `getUsedProducts` that should `Retrieve array of "subproducts"` and returns a collection of products.

There are no changes that I can see when comparing a local repo from 1.9.0.1 to 1.9.1 so its a slight mystery. Even stranger that you are being returned stock but name is null.. Both should be present in the model as they are required fields. Perhaps the module does some additional modifications to the collection that is effecting core behaviour.

But to answer the question. I cant see anything that has changed between these two versions.

Comment: According to the theme developer, there is a bug in CE 1.9.1.0 causing this. The developer has now fixed this issue within his theme as of Feb 23, 2015. I will definitely attempt to get more details from him as to what the bug was and how he fixed it. Sorry I don't have more details to share yet as I've been recovering from a nasty health issue and haven't been digging in the code yet to see what was changed. I hope to do that quite soon. Good news is that it's all working again.

Answer (score 1):

I solve this with this line

```
<?php $childProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($childProduct->getId()); ?>
```

So I get all the childProduct info, and now the getName gets what we expect.

I hope this helps! not the best way, but works.

Answer (score 0):

First, do you even have valid product objects in the loop? i.e. Is `$childProduct->getId()` retuning an ID or `null`? If so, something broke when you upgraded. Please note that `$this->getProductStockQty()` and `$childProduct->getName()` are *not* the same method. So, they don't neccessarily have to mutually work together or fail together.

Second, you would need to examine the respective block's `getChildProducts()` method. From there, you can trace how the collection is put together. It might be be because the collection (for whatever reason after you upgraded) doesn't include the `name` field in its `addAttributeToFilter()` filter.